# How do I submit Material UI Sign In example?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I've created a SignIn component [using Material UI's example](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/tree/master/docs/src/pages/getting-started/page-layout-examples/sign-in).

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import Avatar from '@material-ui/core/Avatar';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import CssBaseline from '@material-ui/core/CssBaseline';
import FormControl from '@material-ui/core/FormControl';
import FormControlLabel from '@material-ui/core/FormControlLabel';
import Checkbox from '@material-ui/core/Checkbox';
import Input from '@material-ui/core/Input';
import InputLabel from '@material-ui/core/InputLabel';
import LockOutlinedIcon from '@material-ui/icons/LockOutlined';
import Paper from '@material-ui/core/Paper';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import withStyles from '@material-ui/core/styles/withStyles';

const styles = theme => ({
  main: {
    width: 'auto',
    display: 'block', // Fix IE 11 issue.
    marginLeft: theme.spacing.unit * 3,
    marginRight: theme.spacing.unit * 3,
    [theme.breakpoints.up(400 + theme.spacing.unit * 3 * 2)]: {
      width: 400,
      marginLeft: 'auto',
      marginRight: 'auto',
    },
  },
  paper: {
    marginTop: theme.spacing.unit * 8,
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'column',
    alignItems: 'center',
    padding: `${theme.spacing.unit * 2}px ${theme.spacing.unit * 3}px ${theme.spacing.unit * 3}px`,
  },
  avatar: {
    margin: theme.spacing.unit,
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.secondary.main,
  },
  form: {
    width: '100%', // Fix IE 11 issue.
    marginTop: theme.spacing.unit,
  },
  submit: {
    marginTop: theme.spacing.unit * 3,
  },
});

function SignIn(props) {
  const { classes } = props;

  return (
    <main className={classes.main}>
      <CssBaseline />
      <Paper className={classes.paper}>
        <Avatar className={classes.avatar}>
          <LockOutlinedIcon />
        </Avatar>
        <Typography component="h1" variant="h5">
          Sign in
        </Typography>
        <form className={classes.form}>
          <FormControl margin="normal" required fullWidth>
            <InputLabel htmlFor="email">Email Address</InputLabel>
            <Input id="email" name="email" autoComplete="email" autoFocus />
          </FormControl>
          <FormControl margin="normal" required fullWidth>
            <InputLabel htmlFor="password">Password</InputLabel>
            <Input name="password" type="password" id="password" autoComplete="current-password" />
          </FormControl>
          <FormControlLabel
            control={<Checkbox value="remember" color="primary" />}
            label="Remember me"
          />
          <Button
            type="submit"
            fullWidth
            variant="contained"
            color="primary"
            className={classes.submit}
          >
            Sign in
          </Button>
        </form>
      </Paper>
    </main>
  );
}

SignIn.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

export default withStyles(styles)(SignIn);
```

Now I want to use it in a parent component with a submit handler. But I can't figure out how to execute the handler when the form in the child component is submitted

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import SignIn from "../components/SignIn";

export default class Login extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
        };

        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    handleSubmit = async event => {
        // Do Stuff
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="Login">
                <SignIn onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: I suggest you also add the child component's code. From the parent, everything seems fine.

Comment: Can you elaborate on 'how to get into the handler on submit'? What do you mean by that?

Comment: @Nifled The child component's code is literally the code I linked to in the example. I'll edit the question to have everything in one page.

Comment: @KatiaWheeler I want to execute the handler when the form from the child component is submitted

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your button in the `SignIn` component to call the submit handler passed in through the props like so:

```
<Button
    type="submit"
    fullWidth
    variant="contained"
    color="primary"
    className={classes.submit}
    onClick={this.props.onSubmit}
    >
        Sign in
    </Button>
```

Comment: This or you can add it on the form itself (for semantics). `<form onSubmit={this.props.onSubmit} ...>`

Comment: I was pretty sure I'd tried that but apparently I didn't. Thanks, that works and I should take a break...! If anyone's wondering, form data is available in event.target in the handler.